# Вывод строки в bash

Tags: linux, bash, grep, sed, awk

Привет! Есть лог с некими строками

```
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: 123
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: ewew
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: sdfgt3342
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: xzczx
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: 123345
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: -%#Q54qas>#!@#!<!
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: ><><@><#!
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: 00000
    Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: @#!@#!@
```

Подскажите как вывести в консоль всё, что после "DUMPER: " ?

Answer (score 3):

удалить всё с начала строки, включая указанную подстроку можно, например, так:

```
$ sed 's/.*подстрока//' файл
```

---

в данном конкретном случае:

```
$ sed 's/.*DUMPER: //' файл
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с помощью awk:

```
awk '{print $6}' file.log
```

если нужно отобразить всю строку после нужной колонки (вместо 6 указываем нужную позицию):

```
 awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' file.log
```

Comment: если в строке после `DUMPER:` будут пробелы, то не сработает же?

Comment: почему же, сработает. Удобство awk как раз в том что он в отличии от того же cut игнорирует количество пробелов и он обьединяет их в 1 разделитель.

Comment: @beily Для строки `Mar  8 09:36:02 test-test DUMPER: @#!@#!@ !!!` будет выведено `@#!@#!@`, а не `@#!@#!@ !!!`

Comment: для такого случая можно решить 2 способами:
1) если может быть 1 значение с пробелом и это конец строки:

awk '{print $6, $7 }' file.log

2) если нужно отобразить всю строку посленужной колонки:

     awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 6; i <= NF; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' file.log

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так: `sed 's/.*DUMPER: \(.*\)$/\1/g'` ([c](https://www.opennet.ru/openforum/vsluhforumID9/7769.html))

Answer (score 0):

За отправную точку взяты пробелы в качестве разделителей. Тут выплёвывается всё, что идёт после 11-го пробела:

```
cat file.log | cut -d ' ' -f 11
```

Comment: Очередной *Useless use of cat*?

Comment: @0andriy, можно `cut -d ' ' -f 11 file.log`, но мне нравится разделять пути и собсно обработку.

Comment: Хотя и разумен, такой подход не для shell.

Comment: @0andriy, почему?

Comment: Ну сами уж подумайте. Может, кстати, быть вопросом для интервью (сисадмин - девопс).

Comment: @0andriy, не проканает с очень большими файлами?

Comment: Это только начало. Думайте дальше. Подсказки такие: а) обвалиться может и на файле нулевой длины; б) файлы бывают разными не только по длине; в) программы, которые читают из файла, могут читать его по-разному. Рекомендую как-нибудь поинтервьюироваться в Google на SRE, если даже не собираетесь там работать. Увлекательно.

Comment: @0andriy, ну ответ дан для конкретного файла с конкретным синтаксисом и под конкретную задачу. Так что некоторые "подводные камни" просто неактуальны. Про SRE посмотрю.

Comment: Когда плохой стиль входит в привычку... Впрочем, я пожалуй остановлюсь здесь. Если вам интересно саморазвитие, покопайте вопросы выше, а если нет, не обижайтесь.

Comment: @0andriy, обязательно покопаю, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Привет

Вариант использующий regex

```
 grep -oP "(? <=DUMPER: ).+" your-log-file
```

**Ссылки**

- http://regular-expressions.mobi/refadv.html?wlr=1
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973495/3295105